# Store UserName in Preferences Bundle of WebView iOS App?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, nsuserdefaults, preferences

Is there a way to create a settings/preferences bundle that stores the username of a form in a UIWebView?

In my App I use a UIWebView that requires username and password. I don't want to store the password, only the username - and the user should be able to set his username in the preferences, which are then automatically loaded when the UIWebView shows.

I know this has to do with NSUserDefaults, but I cant seem to implement it correctly. I know the name of the form fields if that helps?

It's this URL in which I need the user to be able to type in a standard username in the preferences, that are loaded when the App starts: http://stanley.djk.dk

I dont want to use the keychain method.

Answer (score 0):

The flow should be as follows:

1. User set his [username] using some UI you provide
2. [username] is stored using UserDefaults, just as you suggested
3. Finally, the user wants to visit the webpage, so you open it in your webview
4. After the page is fully loaded, you read previously stored [username] from userdefaults and inject it into the webview using UIWebView's method:

   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

in case of that particular website, you should run this script:

```
document.getElementById("modlgn-username").set("value", "[username]")
```